# Почему после вызова генератора выводится именно ЭТО?

Tags: php, массивы, генераторы

```
<?php 
 function simple($from = 1, $to = 100) {
     for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
        echo "$i<br>";
         yield $i;
     }
 }
 $generator = simple(1, 5);
 foreach ($generator as $val) {
     echo $val . "<br>";
 }
```

Вывод такой:

> 1
>  1
>  2
>  2
>  3
>  3
>  4
>  4
>  5
>  5

Насколько я понимаю должен был получится такой вывод:

> 1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>  5
>  1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>  5

Ведь я сначала вызываю генератор, когда пишу `$generator = simple(1, 5)` и должен выполняться вывод от 1 до 5. И потом я вызываю `foreach`, который выводит значения переменной `$generator`.

Почему вышло не так, как ожидалось?

Comment: Потому что вы выводите дважды, как в функции с генератором так и в цикле

Comment: потому что именно в этом и состоит весь смысл и вся суть генераторов. при любом другом выводе использование генератора будет абсолютно бессмысленно

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я всё понял

Answer (score 0):

> Вся суть генератора заключается в ключевом слове yield. В самом простом варианте оператор "yield" можно рассматривать как оператор "return", за исключением того, что вместо прекращения работы функции, "yield" только приостанавливает ее выполнение и возвращает текущее значение, и при следующем вызове функции она возобновит выполнения с места, на котором прервалась.

Для понимания работы генераторов лучше подойдёт пример из официальной документации:

```
function gen_one_to_three() {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        // Обратите внимание, что $i сохраняет свое значение между вызовами.
        yield $i;
    }
}

$generator = gen_one_to_three();
foreach ($generator as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

Результат будет следующий:

> 1
>   2
>   3

Почитайте документацию там есть еще примеры и всё подробно расписано:
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: Наоборот, пример из вопроса более показателен.

Comment: Вы могли просто дать ссылку на документацию учитывая что вы просто скопировали из документации

Comment: @Walfter по правилам Stack Overflow нужно именно что скопировать

Comment: Я понял почему вывод такой. В `foreach` вызывается $generator, соответственно выводится срабатывает инструкция `echo $i`, после чего уже в теле цикла еще раз выводится значение

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за ответы